# bootstrap popover needs double click in order to be triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I have a div when clicked it is supposed to trigger a popover and show a separate div and it works fine. The problem is after the popover is displayed when you click on the external div it removes the popover but after removing the popover when you click on the popover div to show the popover again you have to click twice in order to trigger it. Why does it need to be clicked twice? how can I fix this so that it always works with one click? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

**Update:**

I tried using this to solve it but it doesn't work too.
It completely doesn't work on bootstrap 5 but on bootstrap 4 its able to catch that the click didn't trigger the popover but the solution doesn't work. Tried solution:

```
$('body').on('hidden.bs.popover', function (e) {
    $(e.target).data("bs.popover")._activeTrigger.click = true
});
```

```js
$(function() {
  $(".testDiv").popover({
    container: 'body',
    html: true,
    placement: 'bottom',
    sanitize: false,
    content: function() {
      $('.testDivCon').show()
      $('.wifiInfoContent').append('<button class="testButton">Click Me</button>')
      return $('.wifiInfoContent').html();
    }
  });

});

$('.testDivCon').on('click', function() {
  $('.popover').remove()
  $('.testDivCon').hide()
})

$(document).on('click', '.testButton', function() {
  console.log('clicked')
})
```

```css
.testDivCon {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}

.testDiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 20%;
  width: 20%;
  height: 15%;
  background-color: black;
}

.wifiInfoContent {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="testDivCon"></div>
<div class="testDiv"></div>

<div class="wifiInfoContent"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to correctly remove the popover:

```
$('.testDiv').popover('hide');
```

```js
$(function() {
  $(".testDiv").popover({
    container: 'body',
    html: true,
    placement: 'bottom',
    sanitize: false,
    content: function() {
      $('.testDivCon').show()
      $('.wifiInfoContent').append('<button class="testButton">Click Me</button>')
      return $('.wifiInfoContent').html();
    }
  });

});

$('.testDivCon').on('click', function() {
  $('.testDiv').popover('hide');
  $('.testDivCon').hide();
})

$('.testDiv').on('click',function() {
  $('.testDivCon').hide()
});

$(document).on('click', '.testButton', function() {
  console.log('clicked')
});
```

```css
.testDivCon {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}

.testDiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 20%;
  width: 20%;
  height: 15%;
  background-color: black;
}

.wifiInfoContent {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="testDivCon"></div>
<div class="testDiv"></div>

<div class="wifiInfoContent"></div>
```

---

---

You don't need jQuery to achieve this and can perfectly do this in bootstrap 5 as well:

```js
const popoverTrigger = document.querySelector('.testDiv');
const popover = new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTrigger, {
  html: true,
  sanitize: false,
  content: '<button class="testButton">Click Me</button>'
});

let testDivConShown = false;

popoverTrigger.addEventListener('click', function(){
  testDivConShown = !testDivConShown;
  document.querySelector('.testDivCon').style.display = testDivConShown ? 'block' : 'none';
});

document.querySelector('.testDivCon').addEventListener('click', function() {
    popover.hide();
    testDivConShown = false;
    document.querySelector('.testDivCon').style.display = 'none';
});
  
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if(e.target.classList.contains('testButton'))
  console.log('button clicked');
});
```

```css
.testDivCon {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}

.testDiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 20%;
  width: 20%;
  height: 15%;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="testDivCon"></div>
<div class="testDiv" data-bs-container="body" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-placement="bottom"></div>

<div id="wifiInfoContent" class="d-none"><button class="testButton">Click Me</button></div>
```

Comment: thanks this works didn't see your answer.

Comment: hi, when I try and apply this method for multiple popovers on multiple divs it doesn't work. The problem is once I activate the popover on one of the popover trigger divs that specific div will work to trigger the popover but the other popover trigger divs don't trigger their popover. Do you have any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: never mind changed ```$('.testDiv').popover('hide');``` to ```$('.popover').popover('hide');``` to hide all active popovers at once and it worked for multiple popovers.